# why my dnn dosen't works?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

input_dim=784
layer1_dim=10
#relu-renorm-layer 650dim

layer2_dim=100
layer3_dim=100
layer4_dim=100
layer5_dim=10

learning_rate=0.5

# train_data=np.loadtxt("g_data.txt",dtype=float).astype("float")
# train_target=train_data[:,-layer5_dim:]
# train_feature=train_data[:,0:-layer5_dim]
# test_data=np.loadtxt("g_data.txt",dtype=float).astype("float")
# test_target=test_data[:,-layer5_dim:]
# test_feature=test_data[:,0:-layer5_dim]

#print(train_target.shape)

x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

w1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_dim,layer1_dim]))
w2=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer1_dim,layer2_dim]))
w3=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer2_dim,layer3_dim]))
w4=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer3_dim,layer4_dim]))
w5=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer4_dim,layer5_dim]))

b1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,layer1_dim]))
b2=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,layer2_dim]))
b3=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,layer3_dim]))
b4=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,layer4_dim]))
b5=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,layer5_dim]))

layer_1 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w1), b1))
layer_2 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, w2), b2))
layer_3 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, w3), b3))
layer_4 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, w4), b4))
layer_5 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_4, w5), b5))

#loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(layer_5-y))
loss=tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(layer_1), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    # we'll make 5000 gradient descent iteration
    for i in range(1000):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        _,err =session.run([train_op,loss], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})
        print(err)
    #print(session.run(layer_5,feed_dict={x:test_feature,y:test_target}))
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(layer_5, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print(session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

I followed the tutorial in tensorflow. However the dnn of my code can not work as well as the tutorial's MNIST For ML Beginners.

Is there whether my code wrong or just dnn that can not work with this problem?

By the way,my code's accuracy is 10%,which less than tutorial's 92%.

Comment: As you're training with batches, I'd say first that your placeholders should be: x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
and y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

Comment: You only train your first layer since it's your parameter for your loss function, all the next layers don't update. You should then compute this for your accuracy: 
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(**layer_1**, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

Comment: @AnthonyD'amato The problem is not in here.

Comment: @AnthonyD'amato Thanks a lot!But I want to know that why 5 layers that I used before is less than 1 layer.

Comment: Because you actually don't train this layer in your example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try doing this, I obtained 91%:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

input_dim=784
layer1_dim=10
learning_rate=0.3

layer2_dim=100
layer3_dim=100
layer4_dim=100
layer5_dim=10



x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_dim])
y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

w1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_dim,layer1_dim]))
w2=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer1_dim,layer2_dim]))
w3=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer2_dim,layer3_dim]))
w4=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer3_dim,layer4_dim]))
w5=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer4_dim,layer5_dim]))

b1=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,layer1_dim]))
b2=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,layer2_dim]))
b3=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,layer3_dim]))
b4=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,layer4_dim]))
b5=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,layer5_dim]))

layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w1), b1))
layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, w2), b2))
layer_3 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, w3), b3))
layer_4 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, w4), b4))
layer_5 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_4, w5), b5))

loss=tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(layer_5), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    # we'll make 5000 gradient descent iteration
    for i in range(10000):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(128)
        _,err =session.run([train_op,loss], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})
        print(err)
    #print(session.run(layer_5,feed_dict={x:test_feature,y:test_target}))
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(layer_5, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print 'ACCURACY'
    print(session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The main bug is using only one layer network for computing loss. You should use all network not only first later. So, Please use `layer_5` instead of `layer_1` in the cost function. 
And I recommend replacing your cost function with `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.